# How to satisfy the "consistent-return" rule in eslint using an if-error-return pattern?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have some code:

```
foo((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    // do something with data
});
```

This will cause a "consistent-return" error to be returned. I understand that this is an opinionated matter, however, what would be a reasonable way to satiate this rule?

Is my approach even correct? Should I be using return to effectively "break" within the callback body? Would I have to add an empty `return` statement after the `// do something with data` lines had been executed?

Comment: at `do something with data` do you need to return anything? If not perhaps `if..else`?

Comment: Does your `do something with data` end with something being returned? If so, what's the significance of the return value?

Comment: The return value has no significance - imagine I just log the contents of what's in `data`

Answer (score -1):

Consistent-return indicates that your function should always return the same type of data. So if you're returning `undefined` in a error case, you also should return `undefined` in the other cases.

```js
foo((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    return;
});
```

If your function is supposed to return data when error is false, maybe your don't want to return `undefined`, and throw an `Error` instead.

```js
foo((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        throw new Error()
    }

    return data; // or anything else
});
```

Comment: The return statement is unreachable if you a throw an error and you get `no-unreachable`  ESLint error.